# Enable random access to collection with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a Rails application. It has a feed that shows items from different users all mixed up. It would be something similar to Pinterest in the way you see these items.

Right now I show all these items ordered by its date of creation. However, as the items are created by batches by users, they are shown not randomly (say you se the first 6 items being from one user, then the other 5 from other one, etc.).

The code that serves the items is this:

```
class Feeder

    def self.most_recent_created(watching_user=nil, current_cursor)

        next_cursor = nil
        feed = []
        influencers_ids = User.influencers.distinct(:_id)

        Rating.most_recent_from_influencers(watching_user, influencers_ids).scroll(current_cursor) do |rating, cursor|
            next_cursor = cursor
            feed << ImoPresenter.new(Imo.new(rating), watching_user)
        end

        feed << next_cursor.to_s

    end

end
```

scroll just gives a cursor pointing to each item in the iteration. Then I push the item into the feed.

The access to the database is done in Rating.most_recent_from_influencers(watching_user, influencers_ids), where most_recent_from_influencers(watching_user, influencers_ids) is a scope defined as follows:

```
scope :not_from, ->(user) { ne(user_id: user.id) }
scope :from, ->(user_ids) { any_in(user_id: user_ids) }
scope :most_recent_from_influencers, ->(watching_user, influencers_ids) {
        proxy = from(influencers_ids).over_zero.desc(:created_at).limit(IMOS_PER_PAGE)
        proxy = proxy.not_from(watching_user) if watching_user
        proxy
    }
```

MongoDB does not have random access out of the box. They suggest [this](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/) for having a way of accessing randomly to the items. Basically, the solution is to add a random field in all documents and order the collection through this field. However, although I would have random items, I would always have almost the same items being shown, as I would just have the options of ordering it by `desc(:rand)` or `asc(:rand)`.

I would like to have suggestions on how I can make the items being shown truly in a random way. Is it possible?

Comment: why don't you sort by some random component of the id, like seconds, or if you have full timestamp stored in the object, then milliseconds... hmm I see that you are dealing potentially with exactly the same set of items and you want to randomize them

Comment: @AsyaKamsky , how would you order by milliseconds in the ObjectId. As far as I know, you just can order by field name.

Comment: you can use aggregation framework to transform any field (I just realized you can't yet extract time from ObjectId in aggregation). What other fields are present in your document?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("547363f5426f72622f000000"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5464e5bf62616e055e050000"),
    "value" : 3,
    "item_id" : ObjectId("5461cc3c426f727f16bcd607"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-11-24T16:59:33.230Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-11-24T16:59:33.230Z")
}

Comment: you can use aggregation $project operator to extract milliseconds field and sort on that - I would recommend sorting on either .1seconds, .2seconds or .3seconds - that gives you three random orders you can cycle through.

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar questions, I've come to the conclusion that having a random field is a valid solution if the collection is dynamic, meaning that documents are inserted frequently. The more dynamic the collection is, the more 'random' access you can have.